# googleads.g.doubleclick.net Asking for Username and Password

Tags: malware, virus

Today, out of the blue on the google page, a window popped up asking me for my username and password. It didn't say what it was for, just googleads.g.doubleclick.net. It then happened on my phone which is linked to the same account. I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue and if anyone could help me. I am really worried. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have seen it. I did, when I opened Google Chrome. I was just on the new tab page, not even an actual website! Many people seem to have encountered this in the past 24 hours:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127667/what-should-i-do-about-gmail-ad-asking-me-for-password
- https://superuser.com/questions/1092011/firefox-googleads-g-doubleclick-net-basic-authentication-prompt
- https://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160621202130AAxY0F2
- https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/358415738179518104/
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/Rt3zSPiSyHk/zdB52fBqAQAJ
- http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/429066-edge-wants-me-login-googleads-g-doubleclick-net.html
- https://techreport.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=118101
- https://forums-windowscentral-com.blogspot.com/2016/06/edge-wants-me-to-login-to.html

The best response I've found is over on the security stack exchange:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/127668/43188

To summarize, yesterday, googleads.g.doubleclick.net (a Google domain that serves ads) either was briefly compromised by an attacker seeking people's passwords, or a Google engineer messed up and it's a result of a mistake in their servers.

The answer on the security stack exchange suggests changing your password, even if you didn't fill it in the popup. The suggest this because, if it's an attack, and the attacker is able to create the popup, they could have added malicious code you *didn't* see.

Also, though in principle I'm not a fan of ad blocking, I've recently realized it's probably necessary these days for security. This incident only demonstrates this. I recommend [uBlock Origin](https://www.ublock.org/), but [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) is also popular.